# A Challenge For You

Tags: discussion, review

This is sort of a follow-up to my previous question, since it's on the same subject.

I want to get the CV queue down to **0**, even if it's only for a few minutes. Therefore, I challenge **every user with 3k rep or more** (there are 506 of us, so this shouldn't be too difficult) to **get the Close Vote queue down to 0**!

There's no reward or anything for this, except the satisfaction of getting rid of all those close votes. It's a plus if you stay on top of reviewing and keep it low, but I don't see that happening.

Let's see if we can complete this challenge!

(To reiterate Seth's warning) **Do it well, though!** There's no point in getting it to 0 if it means we close questions about 16.04 and leave the ones about Kali alone. This challenge is a reminder to do your 20-a-day and help the site out!

Comment: But please please please *do not rush it*.  1 single incorrect review because you were in a hurry is not worth getting it to 0 just because.

Comment: @Seth very good point. I've added it in.

Comment: I'd be happy to help... but I'm banned from reviews until mid-October because I had the audacity to try adding a comment to a post (to help the author) before doing something about the post itself. The instant I clicked "Add Comment" it went *STOP, LOOK AND LISTEN: This was a test* and banned me :/

Comment: @NickWeinberg That happens from time to time :(. Don't worry about it.

Comment: 168 and going down :)

Comment: @Rinzwind yay! It'd be interesting to see how low we can get it before the month ends.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Or do you mean in the non-meta?

Comment: Yep, Zacharee1 meant the main site, not meta. Meta rarely has anything in queue.